# Error when using the ace function of ape package in Rstudio: object "phy" is not of class "phylo"

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to run an ASR analysis and am trying to combine binary data to the leaves of a previously generated tree. I keep getting the same error when running the ace function from the ape package: object "phy" is not of class "phylo". Below is the full code I am running.

```
install.packages("ape")
install.packages("phytools")
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(ape)
library(phytools)

# Read the tree
tree_path <- "/Users/USERNAME/Downloads/aeruginosa_galaxy_tree"
tree <- read.tree(tree_path)

# Read the CSV file
csv_path <- "/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Pf4_gene_results_modified.csv"
gene_data <- read.csv(csv_path, row.names = 1)  # Assuming the first column contains row names

# Use only common identifiers
common_identifiers <- intersect(rownames(gene_data), tree$tip.label)

# Filter the gene data and tree
gene_data_filtered <- gene_data[common_identifiers, , drop = FALSE]
tree_filtered <- drop.tip(tree, setdiff(tree$tip.label, common_identifiers))


# List identifiers in gene_data that are not in the tree's tip labels
missing_in_tree <- setdiff(rownames(gene_data_filtered), tree$tip.label)

# List identifiers in the tree's tip labels that are not in gene_data
missing_in_gene_data <- setdiff(tree$tip.label, rownames(gene_data_filtered))

# Output the number of missing identifiers
length(missing_in_tree)
length(missing_in_gene_data)

class(tree)

# Example: Using a Parsimony model for binary data
fit <- ace(tree, gene_data_filtered, type="discrete", model="parsimony")

# Plot the tree with ancestral states
plot(fit, tree)
```

I assume it is an issue with the ape package and its interactions with my Rstudio environment. I have already restarted the environment, tried it in a new environment, and reinstalled the ape package several times. This issue also appears when I use the Built-In data set from the ape package.

```
> data(bird.orders)
> fit_example <- ace(bird.orders$tree, bird.orders$trait, model="ER")
    Error in ace(bird.orders$tree, bird.orders$trait, model = "ER") : 
      object "phy" is not of class "phylo"
```

Answer (score 1):

`ace()` keeps throwing an error because it expects an object of class `phylo` to be passed to the `phy` argument. If you look at the help file for `ace()` you'll see that the first two arguments (`x` and `phy`) should be a vector of character states and a tree, respectively.

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- round(rnorm(23, 30, 5))
ans <- ace(x, bird.orders)

par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(bird.orders, type="tidy", FALSE, label.offset=2)
tiplabels(text=x, cex=0.7, adj=-0.1)
nodelabels(text=round(ans$ace, 1), cex=0.7)
```

[image]